# Align multiple parts to left and right

Tags: java

Im trying to allign the **button** to the left and the **score** to the right.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
private JPanel buildTopPanel(ActionHandler handler)
{
    JPanel top = new JPanel();        
    JButton button = new JButton("New Game");
    top.add(button);
    top.add(score);

    button.addActionListener(handler);
    return top;
}
```

Comment: Please check out the standard Layout Manager Tutorials:[Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to allign the “button” to the left and the “score” to the right.

The FlowLayout aligns the components in a single line.

Try a different layout manager. For example you could use a `BorderLayout`:

```
JPanel top = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );        
JButton button = new JButton("New Game");
top.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
top.add(score, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Or you could use a `BoxLayout` and add "glue" between the two components. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working example with each layout manager

Comment: Yes, it will. Did you even read the tutorial to understand why it will work? Post your [mre] if you need more help, we can't guess what you did wrong. If it doesn't work, then the problem is not with the code posted here, but elsewhere in your code. That is the problem would be with the layout manager of the parent component that you add the panel to.

Comment: @Bob, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.